# How to parse a angular-ui dateTime string to c# datetime

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime

I know a lot of questions about this has been answered. I have tried for about 3 hours with no luck. I am using angular-ui datetime picker, the format is

> "2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z"

Error message is string was not recognized as a datetime

> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
>      at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at TransparentEnergy.Controllers.apiDocumentController.d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy\ControllersAPI\apiDocumentController.cs:line 67

Controller

```
 string docDate = provider.FormData["DocumentDate"];
 model.DocumentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(docDate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Angular-UI

```
 $scope.open = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
};
$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[3];
```

Update

```
 string docDate = provider.FormData["DocumentDate"];
            model.DocumentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(docDate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason why you are not using DateTime.Parse()?

The format you have specified `"2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z"` is ISO date time format. refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

The one you have shown is UTC time and when you use

```
DateTime.Parse("2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z")
```

you get local date-time. According to the timezone of the server \ pc  you are running code on.

You can use

```
DateTime.Parse("2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z").ToUniversalTime()
```

to get UTC. Does it help?

Comment: no reason. just tried different stuff from examples.  here is what the time format looks like at the string docDate breakpoint "\"2015-02-03T06:00:00.000Z\""

Comment: DateTime.Parse("2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z").ToUniversalTime() is giving the same error

Comment: @texas697 All code sample would give errors. The reason are the quotes in the string. I agree with Jon Skeet that the quotes should be there. Ideally you should get rid of the quotes from the source itself. However, if you want to patch the code for the time being you could use DateTime.Parse("\"2015-02-03T06:00:00.000Z\"".Trim('"') ). i.e. DateTime.Parse(docDate.Trim('"') )

Answer (score 0):

Look at the format you're passing:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

That has no milliseconds, whereas your sample is `"2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z"` which *does* have milliseconds. It looks like you want:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'"
```

Also, I'd suggest using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` rather than the US culture - they'll both work the same in this case, but I think it's clearer to use the invariant culture when you're basically talking about a machine-to-machine format.

You should also include `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` to take account of the `Z`.

Comment: still giving the same error. I updated my question with your code

Comment: @texas697: The code you've posted works fine when `docDate` is "2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z" - I've just tried it. How certain are you about the value you're trying to parse? Ideally, post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem

Comment: this is from breakpoint at string docDate   "\"2015-02-03T06:00:00.000Z\""

Comment: Right, so that contains quotes at the start and end - it's not clear why though. I suggest you look at the code performing the post; I wouldn't expect that to be in the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'

  var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-02-08T06:00:00.000Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: here is what the time format looks like at the string docDate breakpoint "\"2015-02-03T06:00:00.000Z\""

Comment: For example your code from yours Update section working in my VS without exception.